# Error con una relación con constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Intentó relacionar una tabla con otra con el constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `ventas` ADD CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id-personas`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id-personas`);
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> No puedo crear tabla `registro`.`ventas` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

( es un experimento de la universidad para no hacerlo de la otra manera clásica)

¿Qué es lo que pasa y como puedo solucionar el error o no es posible hacer una relación con el constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se deriva de la sintaxis que estás usando para declarar tus llaves primarias y foráneas; es decir estas escribiéndolas con `-` guión medio **de hecho me extraña que te haya permitido crear las tablas con este detalle**, tal vez lo hiciste desde un asistente visual como la interfaz de *phpMyAdmin*.

El gestor al usar guión medio me devolvería un error como el siguiente:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-personas INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

Entonces la corrección esta en modificar la sintaxis de las mismas de este modo:

Toma como referencia este ejemplo:

Personas

```
CREATE TABLE personas(
    id_personas INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombres VARCHAR(20),
    telefonos INT
);
```

Ventas

```
CREATE TABLE ventas(
    id_venta INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_personas INT

);
```

Sentencia `ALTER TABLE` a `ventas`

```
ALTER TABLE ventas ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ventas_personas` FOREIGN KEY(`id_personas`) REFERENCES personas(id_personas);
```

`Describe` a ventas:

```
Field        Type   Null    Key Default Extra
id_venta    int(11) NO          PRI     auto_increment
id_personas int(11) YES         MUL
```

> Recomendación, crea mejor tus tablas desde la línea de comandos de MySQL

Comment: Gracias amigo pero me surge otra duda pero esto y es en otra DB por que si me deja aunque estén en guion medio ejemplo: ALTER TABLE `productos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `productos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id-usuarios`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id-usuarios`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `productos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ip_display`) REFERENCES `display` (`ip_display`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `productos_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id-temporizador`) REFERENCES `temporizador` (`id-temporizador`);

Comment: Desconozco pero te agregaré el error que a mi me muestra el gestor de bases de datos si intento usar guión medio @JuanCamiloRinconGil

Comment: Gracias amigo pero aún siguió el error y modifique las pk, fk y la orden y continuó el error.

Comment: Ya probaste eliminando ambas tablas y creándolas de nuevo desde la consola? @JuanCamiloRinconGil

Comment: ehh no probé eliminandolas desde consola pero intente hacer la petición desde consola

Comment: Yo te recomendaría eliminar ambas si no hay data que se pueda perder y crearlas desde ahi mismo (consola)

Comment: si me funciono haciéndolo de cero en consola muchisimas gracias pero me surge una pregunta ¿ como es mas recomendable hacer una relación del método antiguo o tambien funciona este método?